# Stuck on 'Preparing to partition disk'

Tags: disk-utility

When I add a new partition it gets stuck on 'Preparing to partition disk'.

The new partition is in some empty space in the middle of the disk. As a result of the partition not being there, Windows won't boot because its looking for it.

No error, nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This, and other similar problems are commonly fixed with these 2 methods:

---

### Method 1

Go to single-user mode <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on boot). Type the following:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

Hit enter, and then type

```
reboot
```

and then press enter. Now try making your partition again.

### Method 2

If Method 1 did not work, you can boot into Recovery mode (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on boot), selecting disk utility, then HD and repairing disk and disk permissions. This time make your partition in Recovery rather than in normal boot

Comment: Unfortunately neither method had any effect.

Comment: I shall then keep this answer here for others to learn from, and research further. Also posting a log at the time of partitiln attempt will help

Comment: I've added the partition with GDisk. But I'm not sure what it should be called. Windows is still not loading.

Comment: I dont think that the partition name affects it. I usually hold Option, boot from USB and then select install on partition. Bootcamp calls it BOOTCAMP. I however think thats a topic for a new question

Comment: Maybe its because its FAT and not NTFS.

Comment: Both work fine. If you do FAT, you will be prompted to reformat.

Comment: So how does one fix Window's partition table? Its clearly now out of date.

Comment: I always had issues with the USB booting into black screen rather than partition problems. Making partitions with boot camp in the first place seems a bit more convenient. Installing rEFInd also eases things. I would start with trying to boot into your bootable USB.